# Ubuntu 15.0 (Gnome): touch screen stops working after locking the system

Tags: gnome, 15.04, touchscreen

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 15.04 (Gnome) on my Dell 13 7000, after I lock the system the touch screen stops working, also some Gnome shell shortcuts stop working.

Restarting Gnome shell service solves the problem, until next system lock.

EDIT: Corrected question with new findings.

Comment: Found this solution to create script for restart multitouch mod after resume:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1484947#p1484947
and its work for me!

Comment: I have the same issues with touch screen on Lenovo Flex. The above link doesn't work in my case, it works apparently for another issue with system standup, but not with locked screen. I am able to fix it only by retarting compiz/unity window manager, but it brings some quirks afterwards.

Comment: @Dean, can you please tell me how you restart Gnome shell services? I don't know which command would do that. I'm running default Unity desktop, it seems that it does not work in my case...